# How to set date a week later in angular formBuilder?

Tags: angular, date

I can set the actual date in my `formBuilder` but I can't figure out how can I manage to add days to actual one e.g. a week later. I need this to set a date from and date to data in my app.

here is my code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.workday = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [],
      userId: [],
      dateFrom: [new Date(), Validators.required],
      dateTo: [new Date(), Validators.required],   <-- this is where I want to set the actual date to a week later
      status: []
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ngOnInit() {

this.workday = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [],
  userId: [],
  dateFrom: [new Date(), Validators.required],
  dateTo: [this.getNextWeek(), Validators.required],
  status: []
});  
}

private getNextWeek() {
  let result = new Date(); 
  result.setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7);
  return result;
}
```